# MongoDB MMS-like alert generation

Tags: mongodb, metrics

I'm curious how MMS generates alerts on all the metrics, across all the alert configuration across all the groups across all the accounts.

What I would do is query alert configs and active alerts when a ping with new data comes in, and then generate an alert based on the new data.

However, what if some of the metrics can't be determined from the current ping alone, such as page faults avg/sec. This metric is derived from previous pings.

Would there be a background worker of sorts that polls periodically for every alert config in every group in every account? Or would every new ping quickly go get the last minute/5 minute's data for that metric (perhaps only if such an alert configuration exists)?

Also, when no new pings come in, the averages should decay and fire new alerts or update existing ones.

I get the pre-aggregated metrics as shown in this [blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb), and even reporting, but how does one link this with alert generation and management.

This seems to be non-trivial to solve.